# Need to delete the records from a table based upon "Two" Steps

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is table Emp

```
salid  empid    yearquarter   status  type   datemodified
1       105       20041        a       3     2017-01-01
2       105       20041        a       4     2017-02-01
3       105       20041        b       4     2017-03-01
4       106       20021        a       3     2016-01-01
5       106       20021        a       4     2016-01-01
6       106       20034        a       3     2017-01-01
7       106       20034        b       4     2017-01-01
```

Step 1:With in the Yearquarter if there are multiple rows of types  (3,4) for employerid we need to keep latest date record within yearquarter and the rest should be deleted

Step 2:With in the Yearquarter if there are multiple  rows of types (3,4) for employerid and if the report types(3,4) have same dates then we need to keep the record with greatest sal id 
and the rest should be deleted

AFTER DELETION
THE EMP TABLE SHOULD BE LEFT WITH

OUTPUT

```
salid  empid    yearquarter   status  type   datemodified
3       105       20041        b       4     2017-03-01
5       106       20021        a       4     2016-01-01
7       106       20034        b       4     2017-01-01
```

These are records which are to be deleted because of greatest datemodified issue with in a yearquarter per empid

```
salid  empid    yearquarter   status  type   datemodified
1       105       20041        a       3     2017-01-01
2       105       20041        a       4     2017-02-01
```

These are following records which are to be deleted because of greatest salid issue with in a yearquarter per empid

```
salid  empid    yearquarter   status  type   datemodified
4       106       20021        a       3     2016-01-01
6       106       20034        a       3     2017-01-01
```

I AM TRYING TO USE

delete from EMP  with a case statement

BUT IT IS GIVING ERROR AND NOT DISPLAYING THE DESIRED RESULT

Comment: can you show your select statement first then your delete statement

Comment: If you use a row_number() window function in a subquery, partition by empid, yearquarter and order by datemodified desc, salid desc, all you'd have to do is delete those with a row number > 1.

Comment: we need to select only type (3,4) there will be other types also which we should nt delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If salid is in chronological order as datemodified, @ZLK's suggestion can be used as below

```
DELETE
  FROM emp
 WHERE salid IN (SELECT salid
                   FROM (SELECT *,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid, yearquarter ORDER BY datemodified DESC, salid DESC) rnum
                           FROM emp
                          WHERE [type] IN (3,4)
                         ) a
                  WHERE rnum > 1
                )
```